# How long does the Feast of the Exceptional Rose last?

Tags: fallen-london

The Feast of the Exceptional Rose is currently going on in Fallen London, but I can't find how long it lasts?

I want to know, so I can figure whether to use my Masquing now or wait to get more before getting a new companion/pet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [game's Twitter account](https://twitter.com/EchoBazaar/status/434652303120146432), the 2014 Feast of the Exceptional Rose will last until the end of February. (It started on Valentine's Day.) You still have some time to build up Masquing.

(Note that the Twitter conversation is slightly confusing; [*marriage* is now a permanent game feature](http://community.failbettergames.com/topic7506-the-feast-of-the-exceptional-rose.aspx?Page=7#post58698), but the Feast will end when February does.)